# Conflicting port 80 on nginx and apache Docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, apache, nginx, kubernetes

Is there any way to stop 2 conflicting docker containers on the same machine since they are both using the internal?! or container port 80?
I have one ngnix docker that runs on port 9000 from the browser.

```
916aa1f58ca3        nginx:1.21.6-alpine                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes             0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp
```

and a second Apache2 that is mapped to external port 88.

```
4a3ba2c4847b        apache-master_php                       "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 seconds             80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:88->88
```

They both run together except when I send a request to the apache machine. Accessing the apaches index.html on port 88 on the browser crashes the machine.

Is there a way around this?

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
apache: 
       ports:
          - 88:88
        volumes:
          - ./src:/var/www/html/
```

for ngnix:

```
 nginx:
    ports:
      - "$SENTRY_BIND:80/tcp"
    image: "nginx:1.21.6-alpine"
```

Answer (score 0):

Conflict can never occur between containers, as docker will assign above containers to a private network created specifically for these services and each container will have its own private ip.

docker configuration should be as below, assuming apache is running using the default configurations

```
apache: 
       ports:
          - 80:88
        volumes:
          - ./src:/var/www/html/
```

your configurations is telling docker to map container port 88 to host port 88 which is wrong.

I think you should read the docs
https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: `apache-master_php                     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->88/tcp         
nginx:1.21.6-alpine                        0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp`

I've tried this before. above configuration has just port 9000 accessible from the outside. port 88 gives "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: And this is the docker log error:
`ERROR: for apache-master_php_1  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for php  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).`

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3927 ?